# How to configure Visual Studio so multiple instances have separate icons in the TaskBar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, windows-7, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio so separate instances of it have separate icons in the Task Bar?

[image]

I find this way uses fewer mouse clicks, and I often find  myself opening up one instance of VS 2012 and another instance of VS 2013 just to get this effect (as shown in the screenshot above).

Comment: Have you tried set up the taskbar in that way it is not grouping the icons? Mine is set up so, and every instance has its own icon.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/q/39245

Comment: @SayusiAndo Brilliant, this works perfectly!! If you add this as an answer, I'll mark it as the official answer. And here I was thinking it was a configuration hidden somewhere in Visual Studio.

Comment: Don't put answers in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the Taskbar buttons value (Right click on the taskbar and select Properties) to 'Never combine' or 'Combine when taskbar is full' value.

[image]

Comment: Additional hint (applies to Windows 10): If you have multiple screens and opting to display the taskbar on all of them, there is one setting for the taskbar on the primary screen, and a separate settings for the taskbars on others screens.